# Writing a unit test for add_menu_page

Tags: unit-tests

I am writing a few unit tests for a plugin that I have developed. However I seem to be hung up on testing one (seemingly) simple piece of code.

In the plugin I've written I have registered an admin menu page:

```
add_menu_page(
    esc_html__( 'Places', 'wp-places' ),
    esc_html__( 'Places', 'wp-places' ),
    'manage_options',
    'wp-places',
    [ $this, 'places_page' ],
);
```

But I can't seem to come up with a unit test to ensure this menu item exists. I've seen a few uses of `global $menu`, but when I check the global it isn't yet set.

Here is the very basics of what I have.

```
<?php

class AdminTests extends WP_UnitTestCase {

    public function setUp() {

        parent::setUp();

        wp_set_current_user( self::factory()->user->create( [
            'role' => 'administrator',
        ] ) );

        $this->go_to( admin_url() );

    }

    public function test_admin_menu() {

        global $menu;

        print_r( $menu ); // not set

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than worrying about the internal implementation of the menu code and the globals that it uses (there are several beside `$menu`), I'd use a function like `menu_page_url()` to check if the page exists. That function will return the URL if the menu is registered, or an empty string if it is not. So you could do:

```
$this->assertNotEmpty( menu_page_url( 'my_menu_slug' ) );
```

Additionally, you are not setting up the test correctly. The `go_to()` method only sets up the main `WP_Query` object, it doesn't work for admin URLs. You need to instead call your function that registers the admin menu. So your test would look something more like this:

```
class AdminTests extends WP_UnitTestCase {

    public function setUp() {

        parent::setUp();

        wp_set_current_user( self::factory()->user->create( [
            'role' => 'administrator',
        ] ) );
    }

    public function test_admin_menu() {

        my_admin_menu_registration_func();

        $this->assertNotEmpty( menu_page_url( 'my_menu_slug' ) );
    }

}
```

Comment: ps: we also have a core example for `add_menu_page()` with `menu_page_url()` in [Tests_Admin_includesPlugin::test_menu_page_url()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/tests/phpunit/tests/admin/includesPlugin.php#L30). I wonder if OP was actually writing a core function test?